# My view scope data is not updated

Tags: angularjs-scope

I have an simple AngularJS application with a service holding a collection.

There is a navigation view with a form and its controller adding to the collection. The view in included with an ng-include attribute in the index.html file:

```
<div ng-include="'views/nav.html'"></div><div ng-view="">
```

There is also another view and its controller to display the collection content. This view is called in with a route statement in the app/scripts/app.js file:

```
  .when('/link/list/', {
    templateUrl: 'scripts/domain/link/view/list.html',
    controller: 'linkListController'
  })
```

But this other view not showing anything when I try adding up items in the form at the /#/link/list/ address, and no collection item is shown in the view.

I feel like my navigation controller is not sharing the collection with the display list view.

Here is the list collection controller:

```
app.controller('linkListController', function ($scope, $log, loggingService, firebaseLinkService, LinksService) {    
});
```

Here its list.html view:

```
<div class="post row" ng-repeat="link in links">
  <a href="{{ link.url }}">
    {{ link.title }}
    <span class="url">({{ link.url | hostnameFromUrl }})</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is the navigation controller:

```
app.controller('navController', function ($scope, $log, $location, loggingService, firebaseLinkService, LinkService, LinksService) {

  $scope.addLink = function() {
    $scope.link = LinkService;
    $scope.links = LinksService;

    var linkUrlId = firebaseLinkService.push($scope.link);
    var pathArray = linkUrlId.toString().split('/');
    var linkId = pathArray[pathArray.length - 1];

    $scope.link.id = linkId;
    $scope.links.push($scope.link);

    $scope.link = {id: '', url: '', title: ''};
  };


});
```

And its view:

```
<div ng-controller="navController">
  <form ng-submit="addLink()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="link.title">
    <input type="text" ng-model="link.url">
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I would think my two controllers are root controllers since they are done on the app oject with a app.controller(). Is it the case ? And if so, is they scope then the root scope ?

Kind Regards,

Stephane Eybert

Comment: I don't see any `ngView`, but I assume it is there (or else the route cannot load the view's template anywhere). It is impossible to debug this without the HTML. Furthermore, it is very cubersome anyway, because of the large amount of (mostly irrelevant) code. For such questions, it is always advisable to provide an **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)** or better yet a minimal reproducing fiddle or plunkr.

Comment: Regarding yur edit: There is nothing "rooty" about controllers defined with `app.controller()`. All controllers have equal rights in Angular land. What puts an **instance** of a controller higher in hierarchy, is where thay are defined in the DOM. E.g. an `ngController` on the `<html>` element is higher in hierarchy from an `ngController` on the `<body>` element etc.

Comment: Yes the ngView is in there: <div ng-include="'views/nav.html'"></div><div ng-view=""></div> And thanks for the nothing rooty explanation :-)

Comment: It comes down to the scope in my navController not being seen by the scope in my list.html view.

Comment: Yes. It can't see it since they are sibling sscopes. A scope can only see its ancestor scopes.

Comment: Is my design okay and there is a way to share their two scopes ? Or is my design funky and I should change it ?

Comment: Like I said, if you want one scope to see another, it needs to be a child-scope. It doesn't seem necessary (or reasonable) for the list scope to have to see the navbar scope. If there is stuuf they need to share you could have a parent scope to both. E.g. a `mainCtrl` with two children (one for the `navbarCtrl` and one for the `linkListCtrl`). The shared stuff is responsibility of the `mainCtrl`, for the navbar-spedific stuff responsible is the `navbar Ctrl` (and the `linkListCtrl` doesn't know anything about it) etc.

Comment: Based on the nature of the shared data, a service might be a better alternative for sharing it between controllers.

Comment: I could solve my issue by injecting the $rootScope in both of my sibling controllers and setting the links collection on the root scope instead of on the controller scope. The links collection is thus defined only once, in the navigation controller, like: $rootScope.links = LinksService; Note, this is my first AngularJS app, it's a little demo toy I play with to learn, and is most likely not showing the best data and model design it could.

Comment: I understand. There are many ways to solve issues (not all of them are good practice :)). For your situation a `Links` service sounds like the most reasonable approach. The implementation is similar to what you describe with `$rootScope`, but it's more clean (e.g. you inject the `Links` service only where it is needed). It is not advisable to use `$rootScope` for such things, because it might be needed elsewhere where the `links` are not necessary. It breaks the "separation of concerns".

Comment: Of course, if I could I would avoid using the rootScope altogether but for my cheapo app design it's the only thing that could cut it for me. I'm sure a better design would avoid that. On a more general note, is it common for sibling controllers to need to share model state ?

Comment: I don't know if it's common. But it's not uncommon :)