# Me, AngularJS, and its 3 different ways to specify a controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm confused by these three different ways to specify a controller.

1- I can have an include in the app/index.html file:

```
  <script src="scripts/controller/nav.js"></script>
```

2- I can have an attribute in a route:

```
  .when('/link/list/', {
    templateUrl: 'view/list.html',
    controller: 'navController'
  })
```

3- I can have an attribute in a view:

```
  ng-controller="navController"
```

It's quite a few. I wonder which way to go and when.

Kind Regards,

Stephane Eybert

Comment: if you redirecting on page better it should define in .when({}); block only...
if you want to directly load the page..then you can introduce angular controller by using ng-controller..

Comment: Your 1 has nothing to do with 2 and 3. And there are other places where you can bind controllers (e.g. a directive's `controller` property).

Comment: @pankajparkar Good point. May I ask when you want to have a redirection to the view in a when({}); block and when you prefer a direct load of the view ? Cheers.

Comment: Not so sure about the customary way on SO... Do I have to choose one answer as the solution ? Or can it just stays as it is ? Just wondering... Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (1) has nothing to do with (2) and (3).
And there are other places where you can bind controllers (e.g. a directive's `controller` property).

Each way is serves a different purpose, so go with the one that suits your situation.

- If you have a directive and want to give it a specific controller, use the Directive Definition Object's `controller` property.
- If you use `ngView` and want to give each view a specific controller (as is usually the case) use the `$routeProvider`s `controller`.
- If you want to assign a controller to some part of your view (in the main file or in a view or partial) use `ngController`.

All the above are methods for "binding" a controller to some part of the view (be it a single element or the whole HTML page or anything in between).

Comment: Thanks, I just realized the (1) was mandated and not part of the alternatives, I'm slow today :-) If I understand you, my route controller is ignored in my case ?

Comment: I never said any controller is ignored. If you show some HTML I can tell you more :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought the ngController attribute would supersede the controller in the route. The described full issue in a specific thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083755/my-view-scope-data-is-not-updated

Comment: It usually doesn't. You have to understand that the above ways are not mutually excluding alternatives. They co-exist in any (non-trivial) app. Each serves a different purpose and all work together to achieve the final behaviour. I'll take a look at the othet post.

Comment: I would avoid specifying controllers in both the route and the partial html page. The way I approach this is that you would use approach (3) only when you don't have multiple views in the application.

If you ARE using routing to switch between views, then prefer to use approach (2) as that loosely decouples the view from its controller,which is a good design practice.

Comment: I strongly disagree. I use both and am very happy about it :) I usually use one "parent" controller for app-wide stuff, often a header controller (to control stuff like page title etc), probably a navbar controller (to control the navbar which is visible in all views) and of course a separate controller for each view. But of course it all depends on the architecture (as well as personal preference).

Comment: @AbhinavGujjar You advise approach (3) only when having multiple views, but there are also multiple views we switch in the approach (2). How is the approach (3) tighter coupled ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem That's exactly the kind of design I'm trying to achieve. Only I'm still having trouble sharing the contexts in between these controllers and their views.

Comment: @ExpertSystem I will try your approach of having a parent controller, a header controller, a navbar controller, and a controller for each view. I may come back to you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Im quite new too but Ill try to explain in a more layman way.

1 For each .js file you have (which may contain one or more controller defined), you need a corresponding entry into the script for #1 there. Its not the controller itself, more like to allow script to recognise that this .js file is part of the set of files to run.

2 is more like specify a state or route, which may or may not use a controller. Its much like saying how one event should lead to another. The controller may be involved in the transitions of the states/routes (ie. responsible from one state, to another) or within a view itself.

3 is for using a controller's functions within a view itself.

Comment: A controller involved in a transition.. You can elaborate ? :-) What it is for it to be involved in a transition, and for what reason to involve it ?

Comment: It's not involved in any transistion :) I guess, what Thinkerer is tryign to say is that it is part of what you "transite" to (e.g. you go to route X which basically means: load template Y and let controller Z control it etc).

Comment: Sorry yes thats what I meant, pardon my bad english. 
I also meant that stateProvider also provides for nesting. 
Please refer to this link for more info. 
http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Answer (score 1):

I've added comments to one of the answers, but aside from syntax this may is more of a design question. Here is my *opinion*

Firstly, (1) is irrelevant to the conversation.

(2) is the preferred approach when specifying the controller for the view as it decouples the controller from the view itself. This can be useful when you want to re-use the same view by providing a different controller.

If you find yourself using (3),consider making that area into a directive, since by specifying a controller you are indicating that it requires its own logic.